# Eclipse - Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found (unzip Setup Task)

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-emf, oomph, eclipse-installer

I am trying to install eclipse with Oomph by using a link during the oomph setup

```
(Eclipse Installer >> Advanced Mode >> Eclipse Modelling Tools >> Add user Project (Eclipse Project)
```

and there I am pasting a link to finish the installation.
When I click next and the finish, it produces the following error:

```
org.eclipse.core.runtime.CoreException: Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found.
    at org.eclipse.oomph.util.OomphPlugin.coreException(OomphPlugin.java:291)
    at org.eclipse.oomph.p2.internal.core.ProfileTransactionImpl.resolve(ProfileTransactionImpl.java:428)
    at org.eclipse.oomph.p2.internal.core.ProfileTransactionImpl.commit(ProfileTransactionImpl.java:340)
    at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.ui.EnablementComposite$5.run(EnablementComposite.java:318)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:63)
Contains: Software being installed: artificial_root 1.0.0.v1601316435220
Contains: Missing requirement: unzip Setup Task 1.0.0.201612071748 (com.github.maybeec.oomph.task.unzip 1.0.0.201612071748) requires 'osgi.bundle; org.junit 0.0.0' but it could not be found
Contains: Cannot satisfy dependency:
Contains: From: artificial_root 1.0.0.v1601316435220
Contains: To: org.eclipse.equinox.p2.iu; com.github.maybeec.oomph.task.unzip.feature.feature.group 0.0.0
Contains: Cannot satisfy dependency:
Contains: From: unzip Setup Task 1.0.0.201612071748 (com.github.maybeec.oomph.task.unzip.feature.feature.group 1.0.0.201612071748)
Contains: To: org.eclipse.equinox.p2.iu; com.github.maybeec.oomph.task.unzip [1.0.0.201612071748,1.0.0.201612071748]
```

Do you know how can I solve this problem?

Comment: The log says that the plugin/bundle `org.junit` (of any version) cannot be found (it is not clear to me why it is required by the _unzip Setup Task_). The pasted link is the Oomph script that causes this error when executed, right? If I understand it correctly (but I'm not an Oomph expert), you would have to know the script to tell why or where `org.junit` is not found.

Answer (score 0):

The Oomph installation is missing org.junit, which seems no longer present is recent installer version.
This issue is also reported on the "Unzip Setup Task" github : https://github.com/maybeec/oomph-task-unzip/issues/17
I'm submitting a workaround and fix suggestion there.